# Horse racing: Calculating implied odds from payouts

Tags: probability

At the racetrack, you can see on the tote board, for some bets, how much money you will receive if that bet wins.  For example, the tote might say "DD 5-4, 300 dollars"--meaning, if you bet a daily double (the 2 dollar bet size is implicit) on horses 5 and 4, and indeed horse 5 wins and then horse 4 wins, you will get 300 dollars.

My question: Given this dollar amount, how can I calculate the implied probability that this event (i.e. horses 5 and 4 win) will occur?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If it were a "fair bet" , that is,neither you nor the track has any advantage, the  implied chance would be 2/300=1/150 . In real racing, about 15 to 20 per cent of the monies bet is not paid back. So if you add all the implied chances  for a given type of  bet (E.g. all daily-double combinations) you do not get 1, but about 1.15 to 1.20. If the tote says $300 for a given bet, it means that up to that point in time, 1/150th of the money to be paid back (not 1/150th of all the money bet) is on that given bet.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  And let's say I know what is being withheld by the track--say, 18%.  Given that value, the bet size 2, and the payout 300, can I calculate what the "fair bet" would be?  I.e. the actual probability that this combo of two horses will hit?

Comment: The total bet is P The total payout is P(1-0.18)=0.82 P. The amount  of that particular bet is therefore (1/150)(0,82 P).  Dividing this by P gives 0,82/150 which is about 1/183.